# How can I successfully call python script in R using [reticulate] when having 'multiprocessing' module in python script?

Tags: r, reticulate

I am trying to use **reticulate** package to call python script in R. Previously, it run successfully but this time, the python script includes the multiprocessing module, then I cannot run through. And in RStudio, it always stuck there.

Here is the tested python script, named **test_multiprocessing.py**.

```
# test_multiprocessing.py
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I can run the above script in python, but in RStudio as below:

```
library(reticulate)
condaEnvName = 'myEnv'
reticulate::use_condaenv(condaEnvName, required = TRUE)
reticulate::source_python('./test_multiprocessing.py')
```

The R always stuck there.

Can you please guide me how can we successfully call the python script in R when using **multiprocessing** module in the python script like above one?

I am using Windows 10 OS.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just run the R script from the command line instead of interactively in Rstudio?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thanks. I tried to run using 'Rscript test_multiproc.R' where **test_multiproc.R** is just the contents ``` library(reticulate)
condaEnvName = 'myEnv'
reticulate::use_condaenv(condaEnvName, required = TRUE)
reticulate::source_python('./test_multiprocessing.py') ```, but I got the errors below ```Fatal error: cannot open file '-c': No such file or directory```.

Comment: did you actually do Rscript c:\a_bunch_of_dirs\test_muliproc.R?  If so, try doing Rscript "c:\a_bunch_of_dirs\test_muliproc.R"

Comment: I used setwd() to get into proper dir, and run using: Rscript test_multiproc.R; what do you mean about **a_bunch_of_dirs**?